# Mobile Map disappears on navigation

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm using Qooxdoo 3.0 and started work on a mobile app, but my **OpenLayers** map disappears after I navigate to a new page and then try to go back to the map page. It works fine on a desktop, but not on the **iPad** that I'm testing it on. It almost seems that the map gets pushed behind the page on the show command. Is there a way to move it back up to the top or maybe there is something else happening?  Here is the code:

```
  // Initialize both pages
  var mapPage =  meddv2.page.Maps.getInstance();      
  var controlPanel = meddv2.page.ControlPanel.getInstance();

  // *** show the map page *** - map does not appear
  controlPanel.addListener("back", function() {
      mapPage.show({reverse:true});

  // *** I thought this may help which calls map.updateSize() in the map class 
      mapPage.redrawMap(); 
    }, this);

  // Show the Control Panel
  var controlPanelButton = new qx.ui.mobile.navigationbar.Button("Control Panel");
  controlPanelButton.addListener("tap", function(){
      controlPanel.show();
  }, this);
  mapPage.getLeftContainer().add(controlPanelButton);     


  // Add the pages to the page manager.
  var manager = new qx.ui.mobile.page.Manager(false);
  manager.addDetail([
    mapPage,
    controlPanel
  ]);

  //Show the map page on load
  mapPage.show();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On which device does this behavior occur?

What kind of Map do you use? OpenLayers? Google Maps?

You could try redraw that map on page "start" event.

Might be a rendering bug, please try following CSS statement in your "styles.css":

```
* {
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

It that helps, you have to find out, which div element needs the fix.

These are the styles I applied in qx.Mobile Maps demo. This may help you prevent the rendering bug.

```
#osmMap {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#osmMap > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
}

.olMapViewport {
  position:static !important;
}
```

Comment: @czuendof - iPad (3rd gen) and OpenLayers 2.12.  I tried all of your suggestions and still the same issue. The map disappears and you see a blank screen below the header/title where the map should be.

Comment: I tried your updated set of changes and also played with the z-index and no luck. :-(

Comment: Did you use the qx.Mobile Showcase Maps example as starting point? https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/application/mobileshowcase/source/class/mobileshowcase/page/Maps.js      Please make sure to overwrite the "_createScrollContainer" method and set your map as the new NavigationPage scroll container.

Comment: I did start from there, but apparently I missed something which messes the routing up. Maybe I'll start over using that as a template again. Thanks for your help.